# What are the various ways to manage TextMate bundles?

Tags: text-editors, textmate

I find the capabilities and diversity of TextMate bundles to be pretty good, but even in 2011 there doesn't seem to be a great way to sanely manage TextMate bundles, keep things updated, and add and contibute features back.

There's the [GetBundles bundle](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Review/Bundles/GetBundles.tmbundle) (no homepage... just an SVN repo), which is an admirable effort but still feels pretty patched together and doesn't give enough context for me to choose amongst bundles.

There's the [textmate gem](https://github.com/wycats/textmate), which doesn't do much and doesn't have active development.

Am I missing out on a better way to find, manage, and contribute to TextMate packages? Should I just be more hardcore and manage the packages in my ~/Library manually?

Comment: Consider rephrasing to avoid having this question closed as *not constructive*.

Comment: I don't know what that means :-(

Comment: "not constructive" would apply to stuff that's: "I do this … what do you do?", or any question for a subjective way of doing things. What does "elegant" mean, after all? Question seems okay for me though.

Comment: okay, i tweaked the title to be less subjective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no better ways because not many people care about TextMate anymore. The current branch didn't receive new features since about 2 or 3 years and we have been waiting for TM2 for even longer.

A few weeks ago, someone (not TM's author, though) has posted a quick message on Macromate's blog promising a TM2 alpha for the end of the year. If you are optimistic, maybe you can auto-hypnotise you into believing bundle management will work better.

In the mean time, GetBundles is your best bet. It feels "patched together" because it is. That's the kind of hack people do to keep their old tools going despite the tool's author's lack of long term vision and realism.

I agree with you on the lack of context in GetBundles but you can install many concurrent bundles without worries: TM's bundles are "passive" and are not going to destroy anything. You can test and uninstall them and you can mix and match snippets and commands easily to create your own meta bundles.

If you want to contribute to that ecosystem I believe you need to send pull requests to the bundle's author or contact them directly. Did you check the site? There used to be a very active IRC channel around 2007/2008.

Maybe the whole thing will rise again when TM2 is released but if you want to join a vibrant community and an hyperactive developer I suggest you take a look at Sublime Text 2.

Or learn Vim/emacs.